# Trouble with getting area of figure

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Hw4Problem1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



            double X1 = 35.2270869;
            double Y1 = -80.8431267;
            double X2 = 32.0835407;
            double Y2 = -81.0998342;
            double X3 = 28.5383355;
            double Y3 = -81.3792365;
            double X4 = 33.7489954;
            double Y4 = -84.3879824;

            //Radius*************************]
            double radius= 6731.01;

            // distance=(radius)arccos(sin(x1)sin(x2)+cos(x1)cos(x2)cos( y1−y2))
            double charlotteToSavannah = (radius)* Math.acos(Math.sin(X1) * Math.sin(X2)+ Math.cos(X1) * Math.cos(X2)
                    * Math.cos(Y1 - Y2));

            double savannahToAtlanta =  (radius)
                    * Math.acos(Math.sin(X2) * Math.sin(X4)
                    + Math.cos(X2) * Math.cos(X4)
                    * Math.cos(Y2 - Y4));

            // Get distance
            // distance=(radius)arccos(sin(x1)sin(x2)+cos(x1)cos(x2)cos( y1−y2))
            double atlantaToCharlotte= (radius)
                    * Math.acos(Math.sin(X4) * Math.sin(X1)
                    + Math.cos(X4) * Math.cos(X1)
                    * Math.cos(Y4 - Y1));


            // ******************************************************************************2

            double savannahToOrlando = (radius)
                    * Math.acos(Math.sin(X2) * Math.sin(X3)
                    + Math.cos(X2) * Math.cos(X3)
                    * Math.cos(Y2 - Y3));


            double orlandoToAtlanta = (radius)
                    * Math.acos(Math.sin(X3) * Math.sin(X4)
                    + Math.cos(X3) * Math.cos(X4)
                    * Math.cos(Y3 - Y4));

            double atlantaToSavannah = 
                    (radius)
                    * Math.acos(Math.sin(X4) * Math.sin(X2)
                    + Math.cos(X4) * Math.cos(X2)
                    * Math.cos(Y4 - Y2));
            // System.out.println("distance: "+distance03);

            double rodistance1 = (charlotteToSavannah);
            double rodistance2 = (savannahToAtlanta);
            double rodistance3 = (atlantaToCharlotte);
            double rodistance01 = (savannahToOrlando);
            double rodistance02 = (orlandoToAtlanta);
            double rodistance03 = (atlantaToSavannah);

            double s1 = (rodistance1 + rodistance2 + rodistance3) / 2;

            double s2 = (rodistance01 + rodistance02 + rodistance03) / 2;

            //=√ s(s−side 1)(s−side 2)(s−side3)
            double area1 = Math.sqrt(s1 * (s1 - rodistance1) * (s1 - rodistance2)
                    * (s1 - rodistance3));
            double area2 = Math.sqrt(s2 * (s2 - rodistance01) * (s2 - rodistance02)
                    * (s2 - rodistance03));

            double totalArea = (area1 + area2);

            System.out.println("The area is: " + totalArea);



        }

    }
```

compute the area of land surrounded by the polygon created by these cities.

```
Radius:  6,371.01 km
s= (side 1+side 2+side3)/2
area_of_triangle=√ s(s−side 1)(s−side 2)(s−side3)
```

I am having trouble with this program I am geting the wrong answer, I am getting  7.048521505923942E7
After changing the scale to 3 and rounding is 17516629.000
It should be: 117863.342
I already try different ways and I am still getting the same answers.

Comment: Possible issue between degrees and radians?

Comment: How can I adjust that in Java?

Comment: I don't know if that is the problem exactly. I'm just spit balling. You need to look the algorithm up. The `java.math` class has a method called `toRadians(...)` I believe. The explicit formula is `rad = 180 / PI' where `PI` is define in `java.math', I think. If that's not right feel free to let us know, but that's usually the first thing you should check when using trigonometric functions.

Comment: I converted answer to radians and degrees. I checked the algorithm several times but I am still having the same issue :/

Comment: Where are you getting that answer for the area?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You need to explain your code and how it relates to the HW assignment.  Is part of the code given or did you write it all?

Comment: I wrote all the code, only the formulas were given. I got the area from the formula

Comment: Did you try adding print statements to see if each value gives you expected output? Let us know which one you're having trouble with.